# How Miniaturize telegram bot button

Tags: telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

`$media[]=['⬅️',''];`

It's my telegram bot buttons.

it's very large i don't like this.

How Can I Miniaturize telegram button?

I think i need this : `resize_keyboard`

But i don't know how use this for Miniaturize buttons.

its my function request:

```
var_dump(
    makeHTTPRequest('sendMessage',[
        'chat_id'=>userid,
        'text'=>"Text",
        'reply_markup'=>json_encode(array('keyboard'=> [['⬅️','Button','']]))
    ])
);
```

How Can I Miniaturize this buttons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var_dump(
    makeHTTPRequest('sendMessage',[
        'chat_id'=>userid,
        'text'=>"Text",
        'reply_markup'=>json_encode(array('keyboard'=> [['⬅️','Button','']],'resize_keyboard' => true))
    ])
);
```

Answer (score 1):

what are you mean? you want to change button size or you talk about Emoji?

if about resize, your function should look like this:

```
$reply_markup = array(
    'keyboard' => array(['⬅️','Button','']),
    'resize_keyboard' => true,
    'selective' => true
);

var_dump(
    makeHTTPRequest('sendMessage',[
        'chat_id'=>userid,
        'text'=>"Text",
        'reply_markup'=>$reply_markup
    ])
);
```

you can use emoji as unicode, shortcode or copying raw image.

if you are using PHP, the simple way is to insert Unicode or UTF-8 characters in button text.
this link more usefull for PHP [Emoji Table](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)

also, you can find many different examples on [github](https://github.com/iamcal/emoji-data) and [others](https://emojipedia.org/)

for example, one of my first bot for pizza place :)

```
<?php

define('TOKEN', '<token>');
define('URL', 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.TOKEN.'/');

$bot = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$chat = $bot["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$user = $bot["message"]["chat"]["first_name"].' '.$bot["message"]["chat"]["last_name"];
$text = $bot["message"]["text"];

$menuMsg = "Hello, ${user}! Enjoy a new Banana Pie. \xF0\x9F\x8D\x8C \xF0\x9F\x98\x8A";

if ( $text == "/start" ){

  $Menu = array(
    array("\xF0\x9F\x8D\xB4 Menu", "\xF0\x9F\x92\xB0 Checkout"),
    array("\xE2\x86\xAA Last oreder", "\xE2\x9D\x8C Cancel")
  );

  send_keyb(
    $chat,
    $menuMsg,
    $Menu
  );
}

function send_keyb( $chat, $msg, $keyb ){

  $content = array(
    'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
    'chat_id' => $chat,
    'text' => $msg,
    'reply_markup' => keyboard($keyb)
  );

  curlGET(
    URL."sendMessage?".http_build_query( $content )
  );
}

function keyboard( $keyb ){

  $reply = array(
    'keyboard' => $keyb,
    'one_time_keyboard' => true,
    'resize_keyboard' => true,
    'selective' => true
  );

  return json_encode( $reply, true );
}

function curlGET( $url ) {

  $menuIthem = curl_init(
    trim( $url )
  );

  curl_setopt(
    $menuIthem,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,
    true
  );

  $res = explode(
    "\nDATA=",
    curl_exec(
      $menuIthem
    )
  );

  curl_close( $menuIthem );

  return json_decode( $res[1], true );
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used wrong format for inline keyboard, see following instance:

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]

Comment: My friend its inline button. its not my answer. I want `Miniaturize` buttons. not inline keyboard buttons i want Miniaturize keyboard button you can see in my code !